# Plotting volumetric data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, visualization, 3d-reconstruction

I am working in Matlab and I have a 3d matrix with dimensions 384x512x160, which is made of 384x512 slices.

How can I plot data like that?

Comment: You might want to try Volumetric 3, which can be found on matlabs community page: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/59161-volumetric-3 It's capable of overlaying and rendering multiple sources of volumetric data so long as they are in the same voxel coordinates and stored as 3D arrays. It also comes with a full GUI for editing and creating volumetric layers. [Example image fusing FMRi and Structural MRI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrOYK.png) Disclaimer: I wrote volumetric 3, but it's essentially shareware so use it if it works for you!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What you really have is **Volumetric data**.

I guess that you have is a value of C for every X,Y,Z.
And it actually depends a lot in what type of data you have. You'd need to give more information for an specific answer.

In general have a look to Volumetric data visualization techniques, but there is not just one way of doing this. Following i will leave you some examples you may want to try.

---

## Slideomatic

One option is to use the [Sliceomatic](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/764-sliceomatic) from FE:

[image]

---

## Plotting slices

If you have medical data (or data on a big range)
you may want to use the typical approach of plotting just some of the slices. You can do that using `subplot()` and `imshow(squeeze(:,:, slice))`, or by just concatenating all slices together as `img=[squeeze(:,:, slice1)) squeeze(:,:, slice2)); squeeze(:,:, slice3)) squeeze(:,:, slice4))]`, for example.

[image]

---

## Isosurfaces

You may also just want to plot some equipotential surfaces of your data. You can create some surfaces and plot them using [`isosurface`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isosurface.html):

[image]

---

## Vold3D for indexed images

Or if your image is indexed image you may want to use [`vol3D`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22940-vol3d-v2)

[image]

---

## Pcolor3

A useful tool if you have "smooth" 3D data is [`pcolor3`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/49985-pcolor3), as it fills the 3D volume with semi-transparent surfaces that give the a nice visual 3D perception of "color clouds"

[image]

---

Disclaimer: I have no relation to any of the toolboxes presented here and I chose them by my own opinion. There are probably more, tools for this and if you think you want to add some, please edit the question freely.