# 3D volume rendering in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, volume-rendering

I started with the vol3d function from MATLAB file exchange for the 3D display part but its slowing down the entire application.

I am working on a MATLAB based GUI. Need to display a volume of size 512X512X512, single precision. The display has 4 different views of the volume. 3 standard orthogonal views and the 4th view is the 3D rendered isometric view. 
With vol3D, The display is looking fine but its causing the GUI little lagging and slow. If I remove the vol3d function, the GUI works fine, faster.

I am new in the field of 3D volume rendering. What are the alternatives to this volume rendering in MATLAB. Is there any way to call some C-subroutine using mex, do the calculation in C and display in MATLAB. I have a good GPU(GeForce gtx titan x, 12 gb) but I am afraid I am not utilizing it well for the volume rendering thing.
Any suggestions are welcome. 
thanx for reading :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reconstructing three dimensions image matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659632/reconstructing-three-dimensions-image-matlab)

Comment: vol3D is cool, but computationally very demanding.

Comment: @AnderBiguri, yeah, that's the main issue here, vol3D is doing the job but slowing down everything else. Can the jacket thing for MATLAB be helpful here ?

Comment: "jacket thing"? The problem here is that to render a volume, either you implement a complex rendering function or you use what there is! I linked you to some options.

Comment: Sorry, this is just a link to read about the "jacket thing", http://www.omatrix.com/jacket.html

Comment: Out of the nice options you linked, vol3D is closest to my requirement but computationally demanding, can I do something like do the computation in cuda-mexed function and display in matlab ?

Comment: Yes! you can rewrite the rendering engine to plot faster your data! You have a dev team of 35 people and 5 years to do it, I hope.

Comment: hehe, 5 years !! ,, I don't even have 5 months! but nice to know that computation can be done separately, thanx :)