# display 3D porous media in matlab or any other software

Tags: matlab, 3d, binary, structure

I have a 3D array which demonstate geometry of porous media with zero and one for each voxel relating to the pore or rock of a porous media. I want to demonstrate its structure using a 3D plotter. in the case of 2D imshow in matlab display 2D structure. but in the case of 3D i don't know any software or function to plot its structure. please help me in this case.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I think that you're looking for the function `slice` (with matlab)

Comment: And read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659632/plotting-volumetric-data-in-matlab

Comment: If your image is very big, I'd suggest Drishti (https://github.com/nci/drishti) . Its an open source software for big 3D visualization.