# Multivariate normal distribution ploting for d-dimentional matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, normal-distribution

this MATLAB code plot multivariate normal distribution pdf for a matrix with 2 vector.
But I have a 3 vector matrix. how can I modify this code for my 3 vector matrix to draw shape like given bellow? let the 3rd vector be X3

```
Sigma = [.25 .3; .3 1];
x1 = -3:.2:3; x2 = -3:.2:3;
[X1,X2] = meshgrid(x1,x2);
F = mvnpdf([X1(:) X2(:)],mu,Sigma);
F = reshape(F,length(x2),length(x1));
surf(x1,x2,F);
caxis([min(F(:))-.5*range(F(:)),max(F(:))]);
axis([-3 3 -3 3 0 .4])
xlabel('x1'); ylabel('x2'); zlabel('Probability Density');
```

It is the resulting image[image]

Comment: you'll need to use some volumetric representation of data.

Comment: I am using MATLAB for anomaly detection in which I have data with 3 features. so would you still suggest volumetric representation of data? I am new to Matlab and anomaly detection, its just the start

Comment: None of that information is relevant. If you have a a value `v` for each `x,y,z` then you need volumetric representation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotting volumetric data in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659632/plotting-volumetric-data-in-matlab)