# View of a tridimensional object from a binary matrix in Matlab

Tags: r, matlab, 3d

I have a binary 3d matrix that is meant to represent a 3d object (that is, with the "1"s as voxels that are part of that object, and the "0"s as voxels of empty space).
How can I visualize that object, using Matlab?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotting volumetric data in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659632/plotting-volumetric-data-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1):

This answer applies for MATLAB:

You can use the [`binaryTensorVoxel`](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/43481-binarytensorvoxel) function from File Exchange.

Description:

> A binary tensor may also be referred to as a 3D matrix of zeros and
>   non-zeros or a 3D logical array. `binaryTensorVoxel` will draw cubes
>   where there are non-zero entries in a tensor and leave vacancies where
>   there are zeros.

Example:

```
t(:, :, 1) = [1 0 0; 0 0 0; 0 0 1];
t(:, :, 2) = [0 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 0];
t(:, :, 3) = [1 0 0; 0 0 0; 0 0 1];

binaryTensorVoxel(t);

axis equal;
grid on;
box on;
```

This is the result:

[image: Voxels]