# Plotting 4 dimensional data - matlab

Tags: matlab, 4d

I have a large set of photoluminescence spectra I need to plot. My data has 4 dimensions:

1. wavelength
2. angle
3. excitation freq
4. measured signal

So I have a 1024*4 matrix. I want to plot this either on a 3d surface with color as an extra dimension representing signal strength or in something like a volume plot where the sliced up sections are just normal colormaps. I tried something like this:

```
plottingmatrix=csvread('Book1.csv');

spectrum = plottingmatrix(:,1); angle = plottingmatrix(:,2); wavelenth
= plottingmatrix(:,3); S = plottingmatrix(:,4);

[X, Y, Z] = meshgrid(spectrum, angle, wavelength);

scatter3( X(:), Y(:), Z(:), [], S(:), 'filled' );
```

But I couldn't even get it to work anyone has any ideas how I might be able to do this?

Comment: Please be more specific on how your code fails.

Comment: IS it 4D data, or volumetric data? If its volumetric, check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659632/plotting-volumetric-data-in-matlab/27660039#27660039

Comment: I's not volumetric I just have a matrix with 4 dimensions all of which I would like to plot in one graph I found some example code on stackoverflow and put my variable names in it and so far it only generates an axis and a color bar , no actual plot