# Matlab - Combining slices into a 3-D volume

Tags: matlab, mesh, contour, tomography-reconstruction

I am measuring the crystallites divergence in 3 teeth. Each tooth was physically sectioned into 4 slices and for each slice I created a mesh using Matlab. I represented the data as can be seen in the picture:

[image: slices]

For each tooth, I would like to to stack these 4 slices into one 3-D model using matlab. I would like to be able to view the model from all 3-D directions. Can you please let me know if my idea is feasable and guide me towards the right direction.

Comment: Have a look at some suggestions on how to plot volumetric data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659632/plotting-volumetric-data-in-matlab/27660039#27660039

Answer (score 1):

### Use `surf()` function

If you hold each slice as an image you can use the [`surf()`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) function to display one slice as flat plane colored with the image. If your slice image is stored in RGB format in array `sl` with dimensions [N,M,3] you can write the following:

```
% x, and y coordinates for each grid point
[x,y] = meshgrid(1:size(sl,2),1:size(sl,1));
% Position of slice in z-coordinate
z=0;
% Draw surface with slice projected onto
surf(x,y,repmat(z,size(sl)),sl,'edgecolor','none');
```

To add further slices above or below issue a `hold all` command and place other slices at different `z` positions and repeat the above for next slice.