# Generate a 3D scatter plot from 3D Matrix - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have given a 300x300x300 Matrix.

The first subscript represents the x-value, the second the y-value and the third the z-value.

To access a value of a specific point in the matrix i use:

```
matrix(x-val, y-val, z-val)
```

I want to create a 3D scatter plot where the color of the dots in the plot  changes based on the values of the points in the matrix. All values are `>=0`

As i am pretty new to Matlab i have no idea where to start.

Comment: Are you sure it is not three separate matrices or a 300x300x3 matrix? If your matrix is 300x300x300, it means you have 90000 points in 300-D

Comment: yes, i have generated it using `zeros(300,300,300)`

Comment: is this what you want? Do you have **volumetric** data? I.e. for each x,y,z, there is a matrix(x,y,z) value? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659632/plotting-volumetric-data-in-matlab/27660039#27660039

Answer (score 0):

MathWorks has [a page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/types-of-matlab-plots.html) that summarizes types of MATLAB plots. I've referenced it on multiple occasions. The function you are looking for is scatter3(X,Y,Z,S,C). Walk through the [function's example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html#btr5_il-1), it should help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you can have a 300x300x300 matrix for a point cloud in 3-D. I will assume you have a 300x300x3 matrix, i.e.:

```
x = matrix(:,:,1);
y = matrix(:,:,2);
z = matrix(:,:,3);
```

First of all, you probably want to rearrange points into a 2D matrix:

```
m = reshape(matrix, numel(matrix(:,:,1), 3);
n = size(m,1);
```

Your matrix is now arranged as a n-by-3 matrix, coloumn 1, 2 and 3 representing x-, y- and z-axis respectively, i.e.:

```
m = [ x1 y1 z1]
    [ x2 y2 z2]
    [   ...   ]
    [ xn yn zn]
```

Then you can create a basic [3D scatter plot](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html):

```
scatter3(m(:,1), m(:,2), m(:,3))
```

However, this is not what you want, because points are in the same colour. To add colour based on your colouring logic, you should firstly create a color matrix using one of the MATLAB's built-in [color maps](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html). Here I use `jet`:

```
myc = jet(n);
```

*You can also create your own colour map ofc. Elements in the colour matrix are simply normalised rgb values.*

Now you will have to weight each points using your own logic:

```
weighting = myWeightingLogic(m);
```

`weighting` will be a n-by-1 vector and it should be normalised if it is not yet.

```
weighting = weighting/max(weighting);
```

Now you can colour your scatter plot:

```
scatter3(m(:,1), m(:,2), m(:,3)), [], myc(round(weighting*n),:));
```

---

The full code:

```
m = reshape(matrix, numel(matrix(:,:,1), 3);
n = size(m,1);
myc = jet(n);
weighting = myWeightingLogic(m);
weighting = weighting/max(weighting);
scatter3(m(:,1), m(:,2), m(:,3)), [], myc(round(weighting*n),:));
```