# plot surface chart with one variable the colour of the surface

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have 4 matrices, X, Y, Z & CL. All matrices are 3 x 3 x 3.

I want to plot a 3d surface chart using the surf function. So for example is we say X is the atmospheric pressure, Y is the longitude, Z is altitude & CL is the rainfall. I want the chart to look something like [this chart](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/visualizing-four-dimensional-data.html) where the colour would represent the rainfall.

> surf(X, Y, Z, CL);

I get the error message below. I don't understand what I am doing wrong?

> Error using matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Surface/set
>
> Value must be a vector or 2D array of numeric type

Comment: The input arrays of [surf](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) shall be 2D arrays while you using 3D arrays as input. You can check this example: `[x,y,z]=peaks(33);CL=rand(33,33);surf(x,y,z,CL)`, With a 3D input arrays perhaps you can plot 3 surface.

Comment: You may have [Volumetric data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659632/plotting-volumetric-data-in-matlab/27660039#27660039). Is that correct?