# 4D Heat Map within box

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a box with dimensions x, y, z.
The temperatures taken at different locations of the box are given below.

```
xdata = [122 122    0   245 122 40  122 122 40  205 122 122 122 122 122];
ydata = [0  800 400 400 400 430 30  770 400 400 400 400 400 400 400];
zdata = [150    150 150 150 150 150 75  75  75  75  75  25  75  150 200];
thidata = [24 32 15 13 29 11 23 7 19 24 28 18 15];
```

For example when the location x,y,z is  (122, 0, 150) the temperature was measured as 24.

I would like to create a 4D plot showing the temperature distribution inside the box with dimensions  [0 250], [0 800], [0 300].

[image: Example image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659632/plotting-volumetric-data-in-matlab/27660039#27660039